Problem of type cast between C# and Delphi
I have a C# library with this method in it:
public void writeSimulator(byte[] data, byte nombre)

So SendBuff is an array of bytes.
In Delphi, I import the library and have this in the import:
// *********************************************************************//
// Déclaration de classe proxy de serveur OLE
// Objet serveur        : TSimulator
// Chaîne d'aide : 
// Interface par défaut : _Simulator
// DISP Int. Déf. ?     : No
// Interface événements : 
// TypeFlags            : (2) CanCreate
// *********************************************************************//
  TSimulator = class(TOleServer)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure Connect; override;
    procedure ConnectTo(svrIntf: _Simulator);
    procedure Disconnect; override;
    function Equals(obj: OleVariant): WordBool;
    function GetHashCode: Integer;
    function GetType: _Type;
    procedure writeSimulator(data: PSafeArray; nombre: Byte);
    procedure readSimulator(var data: PSafeArray; nombre: Byte);

Then in my code I call writeSimulator like this:
MCMT2021.VoieAD.writeSimulator(PSafeArray(SendBuff), NumbyteWrite);

SendBuf being an array of bytes.
I get thrown out by typecasting, and if I don't put it in too!!!
Thanks for your help
Michel

This isn't about type casting. You're either making an interop call from Delphi to C#, or C# to Delphi (it's unclear). Or, since the comments mention OLE, you should be using COM with C# instead of native calls. This is either an interop question, or the wrong technology is used

byte[] data isn't just an array of bytes or a pointer to memory. .NET arrays have specific lengths, similar to COM arrays. In fact, it would be a lot easier to expose the C# objects as COM objects instead of trying to call methods as if they were C methods

PSafeArray is a pointer to an OLE SAFEARRAY structure.
Introducing the SAFEARRAY Data Structure
You can't simply type-cast a plain Delphi array into a PSafeArray, as they are not compatible types.  You need to create a SAFEARRAY properly and copy your byte data into it.
You can use the OLE SafeArrayCreate() or SafeArrayCreateVector() function to create a SAFEARRAY, and then use the SafeArrayAccessData() function to access the memory block of the array's data, eg:
uses
  // if you want to use SafeArrayCreateVector(), uncomment 'ActiveX'...
  ..., Ole2{, ActiveX};

var
  bounds: TSafeArrayBound;
  psa: PSafeArray;
  pdata: Pointer;
begin
  bounds.cElements := NumbyteWrite;
  bounds.lLbound := 0;
  psa := SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, @bounds);
  // or:
  // psa := SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UI1, 0, NumbyteWrite);
  if psa = nil then OleCheck(E_OUTOFMEMORY);
  try
    OleCheck(SafeArrayAccessData(psa, pdata));
    try
      Move(SendBuff[0], pdata^, NumbyteWrite);
    finally
      OleCheck(SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa));
    end;
    MCMT2021.VoieAD.writeSimulator(psa, NumbyteWrite);
  finally
    SafeArrayDestroy(psa);
  end;
end;

Alternatively, Delphi has native support for SAFEARRAY in its Variant and OleVariant types. In this case, you can use the RTL's VarArrayCreate() and VarArrayLock() functions, and then pull out the PSafeArray pointer using the VarArrayAsPSafeArray() function, eg:
uses
  ..., Variants;

var
  v: Variant;
  pdata: Pointer;
begin
  v := VarArrayCreate([0,NumbyteWrite-1], varByte);
  pdata := VarArrayLock(v);
  try
    Move(SendBuff[0], pdata^, NumbyteWrite);
  finally
    VarArrayUnlock(v);
  end;
  MCMT2021.VoieAD.writeSimulator(PSafeArray(VarArrayAsPSafeArray(v)), NumbyteWrite);
end;


OK, I have found how to create a SafeArray and now I have received it properly. My last problem is how to give the mysafeArray.pvData pointer to my own byte array in Delphi. I have tried something like: tableau:=PbyteArray(MaSafeArray.pvData) but it doesn't work.

@michastro Sorry, you can't make the pvData member point at your own memory buffer. The pvData is valid only while the SAFEARRAY is locked, and the act of locking it (via SafeArrayLock() or SafeArrayAccessData()) will make pvData point at an internal buffer managed by the SAFEARRAY.

Ok thank you, now it's working.
